# jQuery template, read data clicking a button tmplItem()

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I got a jQuery template (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl) and a Object() that contains two lists.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Some value
                </th>
                <th>
                    A Button
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="results-body">
        </tbody>
    </table>
<!-- HTML -->

var templateHTML = "{{each list1FromTemplate}}<tr><td>{{= Value}}</td><td><input type='button' name='alert' value='Alert' class='alert'/></td></tr>{{/each}}";

 var results = new Object();
     results.list1 = list1Data; //Retrieved from an ajax call
     results.list2 = list2Data; //Retrieved from an ajax call

$.tmpl(templateHTML, { list1FromTemplate: results.list1, list2FromTemplate: results.list2 }).appendTo("#results-body");

//Here goes the question:

$(".alert").click(function () {

alert(
//Alert the value from {{= Value}} in the same row
);

});
```

Everything works ok except the button with the class alert

How to retrieve data from value "{{= Value}}" **in the same row** when the button with class "alert" is clicked???

**UPDATE:**

Theres a way to retrieve the value using tmplItem() or something?

Comment: Give the td a class/id or wrap the value in a span with a class/id, then use jquery to access it, such as `$(this).closest('tr').find('.value-wrapper').text()`

Answer (score 0):

Give the td a class/id or wrap the value in a span with a class/id, then use jquery to access it, such as `alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.value-wrapper').text())` (comment promoted to an answer).

Another option is to set a property (e.g. data-value) on the input that's being clicked, which you'd then access with `alert($(this).attr('data-value'));`

Answer (score 0):

give id for each td(may be for-loop counter value as id) and call the alert function like this:

```
$(.alert).click(function(){
    $('#td_id').val();
});
```